# iOS adding object to an array from another array base on 3rd array value

Tags: objective-c, ios

EDIT: All array used in my project are `NSMutableArray` class

An overview of what I want to do is from my selectClueView, user can select a number from 3-10. Which represent the number of clue they will play. It will then generate list of  random number between 0 and the `objectArray.count` and add the `NSNumber` into another array known as dataArray. Everything is working fine including `prepareForSegue` which transfer `SelectClueViewController.dataArray` to `GamePageViewController.clueToSelect`

However, I am stuck with loading data into the new array `ds`, from an array that hold all the object `allDataObject`. I am fairly new to iOS and because I had a working function in c#, I tried to replicate it in objective-C, unfortunately it seems that I can't replicate it fully.

In short, I'm trying to add data from `allDataObject` array into `ds` array with `NSNumber` values from `cluesToSelect` array.

Below are the coding which are used. Any help to fix the issue would be much appreciated. If there are any more information that I should give, please let me know.

SelectClueViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)onGoPress:(id)sender {
    [self chooseNumber];
     NSLog(@"Array got %d numbers",dataArray.count);
}

-(void)chooseNumber
{
    [dataArray removeAllObjects];
    maxCount = [numberOfClues.text intValue];

    int count = 0;
    do {

        NSInteger rdmNumber = arc4random()%objectArray.count;
        if (![dataArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rdmNumber]])
        {
            NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rdmNumber];
            [dataArray addObject:number];
            count++;
            NSLog(@"random no - %d",rdmNumber);
        }
    } while (count < maxCount);

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sendNumber"]) {


        GamePageViewController *gpViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        gpViewController.cluesToSelect = self.dataArray;
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
}
```

GamePageViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    daoDS = [[ClueDataDAO alloc]init];
    self.allDataObject = daoDS.PopulateDataSource;
    NSLog(@"%d",cluesToSelect.count);

    [self fillDataSample];

    //for keyboard
    self.answer.delegate = self;        
}

    -(void)fillDataSample
{
    int count = 0;
    do {
       // [self.ds addObject:[allDataObject objectAtIndex:[[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count]intValue] ]];
        ds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        currentClueData = [[ClueData alloc]init];        
        int firstIndex = [[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count]intValue];
        currentClueData = [allDataObject objectAtIndex:firstIndex];
        [ds addObject:currentClueData];

        count++;
    } while (count < cluesToSelect.count);
    NSLog(@"ds got %d object",ds.count);
}
```

EDIT:

I am now able to make it add in object into the `ds` array, unfortunately it only add once. Can someone look at my `fillDataSample` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason as to why it didn't work for my new method of loading object from `allClueData` to a class object `currentClueData` to `ds` was because I did not `nil` and `alloc init` the class object after adding it to `ds`. The object were unable to overwrite their own value like they do in other language. (which was probably why I'm wrecking my brain for doing it in objective C) But after adding in `nil` the object and casting `alloc and init`, its working great now. thanks all :)

-(void)fillDataSample
{
    int count = 0;
    currentClueData = [[ClueData alloc]init];
    ds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    do {
       // [self.ds addObject:[allDataObject objectAtIndex:[[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count]intValue] ]];

```
    int firstIndex = [[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count]intValue];
    currentClueData = [allDataObject objectAtIndex:firstIndex];
    [ds addObject:currentClueData];
    currentClueData =nil;
    currentClueData = [[ClueData alloc]init];


    count++;
} while (count < cluesToSelect.count);
NSLog(@"ds got %d object",ds.count);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the line you point at at the beginning :

```
[self.ds addObject:[allDataObject objectAtIndex:[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count]]];
```

Just a wild guess, but `[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count]` returns an object. You're trying to pass that to another `objectAtIndex:`, which takes an `int` as argument. I'm guessing the error could come from that. You could try using `.intValue` if it's a number.

Edit :

Here's something more readable, considering `cluesToSelect` and `allDataObject` contain only NSNumbers :

```
int firstIndex = [[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count] intValue];
int secondIndex = [[allDataObject objectAtIndex: firstIndex] intValue];
[self.ds addObject:secondIndex];
```

Comment: mmm, does this mean anything that was added into an array automatically become an object? Even if what I added in was `NSNumber` ? Sorry for asking, am pretty new to iOS Objective-C

Comment: NSNumber is an object ! I'm editing my post to give you the line you should use.

Comment: ah sorry, it was 1am at my side when i ask. just woke up. gonna try it now after freshening up

Comment: allDataObject contain other object with multiple fields. I posted the latest coding on the end of the question. still doesn't work for me

Comment: updated more information at the end of question. will be back after my check up to test some more. cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion,

Kindly check this one:

```
[self.ds addObject:[allDataObject objectAtIndex:[[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count] intValue]]];
```

will do your work.

Comment: sorry to ask, but what do you mean in new cocoa style? Is it the one where I have to import cocoa library?

Comment: xcode4 uses literals for numbers...that I dont remember and i dont have mac now, otherwise i wud have checked... :(

Comment: refer this one...NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;             // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]
NSNumber *fortyTwoUnsigned = @42U;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:42U]
NSNumber *fortyTwoLong = @42L;        // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLong:42L]
NSNumber *fortyTwoLongLong = @42LL;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:42LL]

Comment: ah sorry, it was 1am at my side when i ask. just woke up. gonna try it now after freshening up

Comment: tried both of your line, but still can't work. it says incompatible conversion type `NSNumber` to `NSUInteger`

Comment: updated more information at the end of question. will be back after my check up to test some more. cheers

Comment: Please try this solution. It will work.                                                               [self.ds addObject:[allDataObject objectAtIndex:[[cluesToSelect objectAtIndex:count] intValue]]];

Comment: tried before, doesn't work. Tried it again, still didn't work